# Adding SpriteFont in Monogame

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, monogame, visual-studio

My question is probably something you guys have heard before - "How do you add SpriteFont's in Monogame's content manager?" The simple answer to this is, right click the 'Content' folder, go on 'Add New Item' and then you'll find it there. In my case however, there is no SpriteFont.

As far as my development environment goes, I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012. Upon getting Visual Studio, I installed MonoGame 3.2. My project is a MonoGame Windows Project (C#). As far as I can see, there are absolutely no options to add SpriteFont's to the MonoGame content manager. Right clicking the Content folder and going on Add New Item simply gets me this:

[image]

No sign of SpriteFont anywhere, whether I look under Visual C# Items or Online. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

The above is my content manager. If I go on Edit, New Item and then add my SpriteFont this way it will add, however the moment I go on Build, it will say 'MGCP has stopped responding'. This makes me think something is missing... A certain something called XNA Game Studio 4.0. I did some research and found a couple tutorials that tell you to install this, which makes me wonder if it is indeed needed. A friend of mine however is adamant that XNA Game Studio is not needed and that the only thing I need is VS 2012 and MonoGame.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? And is the answer to all my problems XNA Game Studio 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You friend is wrong.  The spritefont content template is part of XNA's additions to visual studio.  Unfortunately they are not easy to add to VS2012.

According to this answer (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/35413/19126), the workaround for adding them to 2012 also involves installing 2010 anyway, so you might as well just install and use that.

Here is another well-answered question discussing the process and linking to various resources.  Good luck.
[How to generate Spritefonts for monogame](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46128/how-to-generate-spritefonts-for-monogame/48575)

Comment: Just to add onto this answer, I noticed that if you go onto the MonoGame Content Manager, Edit, New Item, you can add a SpriteFont Description. Which as far as I'm aware, works exactly like a SpriteFont.